# Display = inline solo aparece microsegundos

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

les comento que tengo problemas tratando de poner un div en visible, ya que solo aparece por unos microsegundos y despues se va, y yo quiero que se quede asi hasta que vuelva a clickear.

```
       <div>
             <asp:Button ID="btnCamera" runat="server" Text="Hacer la operacion con camara" class="btn btn-danger" OnClientClick="mostrar()"/>
            </div>

            <div id="camera" class="bg-light" style="display:none" > 
                 //cualquier opracion
             </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function mostrar() {
    var x = document.getElementById("camera");
        x.style.display = "inline";
        x.style.visibility = "visible";
    
}
   </script>
```

Comment: agrega contenido a tu div o por lo menos propiedades de ancho y alto para que se muestre.

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambie las propiedades en display,
aqui el ejemplo

```html
   <div>
             <Button ID="btnCamera" runat="server"  
              class="btn btn-danger" onclick="mostrar()">
              Mostrar
              </Button>
            </div>

            <div id="camera"   style="display:none; width:50px; height:50px; background-Color:blue; " > 
                  
             </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function mostrar() {
    var x = document.getElementById("camera");
        x.style.display = "block";      
    
}
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que aparezca y desaparezca, te recomiendo usar `classList.toggle()` para agregar y quitar una clase.

Le he puesto !important a la propiedad css porque las propiedades tienen preferencia por los ID sobre las Class, puedes intentar usar en lugar de ID, `document.getElementsByClassName("camera")`

```js
function mostrar() {
 var x = document.getElementById("camera");  
 x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
#camera {
display: none; width:50px; height:50px; background-Color:blue;
}
.change {
  display: block !important;
{
```

```html
<div>
  <Button ID="btnCamera" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="mostrar()">
    Mostrar
  </Button>
</div>
<div id="camera"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener presente que el comando asp:button produce un postback, con lo que la página se refrescaría. Lo que deberías hacer es cancelar el postback. Esto se hace devolviendo un false en la función que invocas y poniendo un return en la invocación en el onClientClick. Quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCamera" runat="server" Text="Hacer la operacion con camara" class="btn btn-danger" OnClientClick="return mostrar()"/>
</div>

<div id="camera" class="bg-light" style="display:none" > 
//cualquier opracion
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mostrar() {
        var x = document.getElementById("camera");
        x.style.display = "inline";
        x.style.visibility = "visible";
        return(false);

    }
</script>
```

Podes ver un ejemplo aquí https://www.variablenotfound.com/2007/11/evitar-el-postback-al-pulsar-un-botn-en.html